# RPM conflicts with itself

Tags: rpm

I am trying to manually install libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm from SLES 12 repository on SLES11.3.

Installation fails with following message:

```
# rpm --install libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
       libffi4 conflicts with libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64
```

I can not figure out why this is happening because my system does not have libffi4 installed.

```
# rpm -qa | grep libffi4
# rpm -qlp libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm
/usr/lib64/libffi.so.4
/usr/lib64/libffi.so.4.0.1
# find / | grep libffi
/root/libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm
```

My question is what is causing conflict.

Output from `for arg in requires conflicts provides; do echo "# $arg"; rpm -qp "--$arg" libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm; echo; done`:

```
# requires
/sbin/ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
# conflicts
libffi4
# provides
libffi.so.4()(64bit)
libffi4 = 4.8.3+r212056-6.3
libffi4(x86-64) = 4.8.3+r212056-6.3
```

Comment: What does `for arg in requires conflicts provides; do echo "# $arg"; rpm -qp "--$arg" libffi4-4.8.3+r212056-6.3.x86_64.rpm; echo; done` output?

Comment: # requires
    /sbin/ldconfig
    /sbin/ldconfig
    libc.so.6()(64bit)
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
    rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
    rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
    rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
    
    # conflicts
    libffi4
    
    # provides
    libffi.so.4()(64bit)
    libffi4 = 4.8.3+r212056-6.3
    libffi4(x86-64) = 4.8.3+r212056-6.3

Comment: See the problem? Your package literally conflicts with itself. Go check the spec file.